# problems quitting java program with 'Q'

Tags: java

I wrote a program to determine a prime number and am required to use 'Q' as the quit function to get out of the program. Below is the code i have written. I am wondering how I would modify  method of quitting the program to make it exit correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
    {
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     int number, i=2;
     String quit;
     boolean prime = true;



     System.out.println("Please enter a number to determine if it is prime, to quit     please enter Q.");
     number = keyboard.nextInt();

     quit = keyboard.nextLine();


     for (i=0; i<number;i++)
        {
           if ((number%2==0) || (number==1) || (number%3==0))
           {
              prime = false;
              }
           }
     if (prime==false)
        {
        System.out.println(number+" is not a prime number.");
        }
        else if(prime==true)
        System.out.println(number+" is a prime number.");
    if (quit.charAt(0)=='Q')

       { System.exit(0);}
```

and my output upon entering 'Q' is:

```
   ----jGRASP exec: java Practice

  Please enter a number to determine if it is prime, to quit please enter Q.
  Q
  Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
at Practice.main(Practice.java:15)

  ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
   ----jGRASP: operation complete.








  }
```

}

Comment: `'Q'` is not a number

Answer (score 1):

When the input through the console is given as "Q", the value of type String is getting assigned to a variable of type int, which is incorrect.

```
number = keyboard.nextInt();
```

The type of in the input needs to be checked, before it can be assigned to a int variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
 number = keyboard.nextInt();
 quit = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Think for a moment about what actually happens here. 'Q' is not a number and so `nextInt()`, [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28int%29), throws an `InputMismatchException`. Your use of `nextLine()` doesn't make much sense following that.

You have a couple of options:

- Use `Scanner.hasNextInt()` to determine if the next token truly is a well-formed integer. If not, read it as a string and check it.
- Use `Scanner.next()` always, and check if it is "Q" before parsing it with `Integer.parseInt()` (being prepared to handle errors there as well).

The `Scanner.next*` functions don't implicitly skip invalid values. The `Scanner` is only doing what you tell it to do, and if you tell it to grab an integer but the input is not an integer, it rightfully complains. It is up to you to use the `Scanner` appropriately and check your possible input cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should read in the numbers as Strings with keyboard.nextLine();
and check first if the it contains 'Q'. If it does, quit, else do, number = Integer.parseInt(yourVariableHere); and go from there

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
 String input;
 int number = 1;
 int i=2;
```

Then do this:

```
 System.out.println("Please enter a number to determine if it is prime, "
                  + "\nto quit, please enter Q.");
 input = keyboard.nextLine();
 if (input.charAt(0)=='Q') 
 { 
    System.exit(0);
 }
 else 
 {
      try  
      {  
          number = Integer.parseInt(input);
      }  
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
      {  
          System.out.println("Please enter a number or Q!");
      }  
 }
```